# MySQL ordering multiple columns not working

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

Here is a query I am working on :

```
SELECT i.*,  
CASE WHEN i.modified = 0 THEN i.created ELSE i.modified END as lastChanged, c.name as categoryname,c.id as categoryid, c.alias as categoryalias, c.params as categoryparams   
FROM mc23r_k2_items as i  
LEFT JOIN mc23r_k2_categories AS c  
ON c.id = i.catid  
WHERE i.published = 1  
AND c.id IN (1,2,3,4)  
ORDER BY c.ordering, i.ordering  
LIMIT 0, 100
```

I am complete newbie to joins and advanced stuff.
The result of the above query is returning catid as follows:

```
c.ordering: 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4  
i.ordering: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5
```

I am looking for order as

```
c.ordering: 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
i.ordering: 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5
```

What change should I do to the query please. Only `c.ordering` columns 1 and 2 is the point of conflict rest of the pattern is good.

To my knowledge `c.ordering` should be ordered first why columns 1 and 2 are jumbled?

`**mc23r_k2_items**

id INT(11)

title VARCHAR(255)

alias VARCHAR(255)

catid INT(11)

published SMALLINT(6)

introtext MEDIUMTEXT

fulltext MEDIUMTEXT

video TEXT

gallery VARCHAR(255)

extra_fields TEXT

extra_fields_search TEXT

created DATETIME

created_by INT(11)

created_by_alias VARCHAR(255)

checked_out INT(10)

checked_out_time DATETIME

modified DATETIME

modified_by INT(11)

publish_up DATETIME

publish_down DATETIME

trash SMALLINT(6)

access INT(11)

ordering INT(11)

featured SMALLINT(6)

featured_ordering INT(11)

image_caption TEXT

image_credits VARCHAR(255)

video_caption TEXT

video_credits VARCHAR(255)

hits INT(10)`

`**mc23r_k2_categories**

id INT(11)

name VARCHAR(255)

alias VARCHAR(255)

description TEXT

parent INT(11)

extraFieldsGroup INT(11)

published SMALLINT(6)

access INT(11)

ordering INT(11)

image VARCHAR(255)

params TEXT

trash SMALLINT(6)

plugins TEXT

language CHAR(7)`

---

**Here is the simplified version of my problem, thanks all for your time. please run the following sql code snippet**

```sql
CREATE DATABASE `test1` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;  
USE `test1`;  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mc23r_k2_categories` (  
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ordering` (`ordering`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;  



INSERT INTO `mc23r_k2_categories` (`id`, `ordering`) VALUES  
(1, 1),  
(2, 1),  
(3, 2),  
(4, 3),  
(5, 2),  
(6, 1),  
(7, 2),  
(8, 3),  
(9, 4),  
(10, 1),  
(11, 2),  
(12, 3),  
(13, 4),  
(14, 5),  
(15, 6);  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mc23r_k2_items` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `catid` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
  KEY `catid` (`catid`),  
  KEY `ordering` (`ordering`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=58 ;  



INSERT INTO `mc23r_k2_items` (`id`, `catid`, `ordering`) VALUES  
(1, 2, 1),  
(2, 2, 2),  
(3, 2, 3),  
(4, 2, 4),  
(5, 2, 5),  
(6, 2, 6),  
(7, 3, 1),  
(8, 3, 2),  
(9, 3, 3),  
(10, 3, 4),  
(11, 4, 1),  
(12, 4, 2),  
(13, 4, 4),  
(14, 4, 3),  
(15, 4, 5),  
(16, 1, 2),  
(17, 1, 3),  
(18, 1, 1);
```

---

**Please run the query below for simulating my problem**

```
  SELECT catid  
  FROM mc23r_k2_items as i  
  LEFT JOIN mc23r_k2_categories AS c  
  ON c.id = i.catid  
  WHERE  c.id IN (1,2,3,4)  
  ORDER BY c.ordering, i.ordering  
  LIMIT 0, 100
```

---

resultset is not ordered by catid

Comment: It should do what you expect. Are you sure it's not doing that? Try adding `c.ordering` to to the `SELECT` list to check.

Comment: I am on this for hours now, first priority should be `c.ordering` but does not seem to work both the sorting columns are `int`

Comment: I don't think it's related to the problem, but why is this a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN? The `WHERE i.published = 1` clause means you will never return rows with no match in the categories table.

Comment: can you post the schema of your relations plz??

Comment: I really have no clue on what JOIN should be used, point here is I have got the resultset(using `left join`), why is the order not effected as desired.

Comment: @user1793325 can u provide original table with data?

Comment: I have added tables structure to my post, please advise..

Comment: @user1793325: as others said, your query is fine (except that you don't need that `LEFT JOIN`). What client are you using to retrieve results? Are you sure the client does not reorder the resultsets?

Comment: I have taken this query directly from my Joomla CMS, both joomla frontend and phpmyadmin show the same jumbled result.

Comment: @fathah: I have added simplified snippet, please have a look. Thanks

Comment: @user1793325 Your query does exactly what you have written, that is order by c.ordering, and then by i.ordering. You can verify what's happening by running this query: `SELECT i.id, i.catid, c.ordering, i.ordering
  FROM mc23r_k2_items as i  
  JOIN mc23r_k2_categories AS c  
  ON c.id = i.catid  
  WHERE  c.id IN (1,2,3,4)
  ORDER BY c.ordering, i.ordering`

Comment: If you want the result set to order by catid, then that should be mentioned in the order by clause. I think this is what you want: `ORDER BY c.ordering, c.id`. Furthermore I think you need a `JOIN` not a `left join`

Comment: @nawfa: is this resultset right?  1 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4

Comment: @user1793325 yes that is, but that's expected given your query. How do you want order to be?

Comment: @nawfal I am expecting 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 since c.ordering is my first priority sorting: in my project c.ordering represent category ids and i.ordering represents articles ordering in respective categories..

Comment: @user1793325 no question about it, but what's your second priority for sorting is the question here. In other words what if you have two same c.ordering? I suppose you need to then sort based on catid. so do `ORDER BY c.ordering, c.id` in your query

Answer (score 0):

The query is actually doing what it intended. Problem was with c.ordering values where in my project parent category has the same ordering value(1) and its first sub-category has the same ordering value(1)
Thanks everyone for your valuable time @nawfal .